# Running a command directly vs. from an environment variable

Tags: bash, command-line, environment-variables

I was trying to compile and execute a program using g++, and then I got the command:

```
g++ -o example example.cpp && ./example
```

And it runs OK. I tried to set an environment variable to save my time:

```
COMPRUN="g++ -o example example.cpp && ./example"
```

(The `echo $COMPRUN` tells me the assignment was all right). But when I try to execute it using `$COMPRUN`, I get `g++: error: &&: No such file or directory`.

An alias works fine (so my original problem is solved), but an environment variable doesn't.

**Why is running a command directly different than running it from an environment variable? How did the command-line interpret my command to get that 'No such file' error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a shell function, not a variable, to encapsulate arbitrary code.

```
$ comprun () {
    g++ -o "$1" "$1".cpp && ./"$1"
}
$ comprun example
```

Parameter expansion occurs after the command line has already been parsed, so any syntactic structures (like `&&`) are not recognized. In your case, the file that did not exist was "&&".

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you got the error is because the shell did **not** interpret the command-line. Because of that `&&` is treated as a simple string (a file name in the context of your command) instead of being interpreted as a control operator. You'd have to use `eval $COMPRUN` to have the shell actually evaluate the command string.